# Stop MacOS Catalina adding SSH keys automatically

Tags: macos, keychain, ssh

Getting a bit annoyed by this now and probably something simple!

I have various different ssh keys that I use to connect to a range of servers as well as a key to access Github.  These keys are all listed as identity files in `.ssh/config` and work well.

However, ssh agent keeps automatically loading a bunch of keys that has the knock-on effect of throwing up a `too many authentication errors` message when trying to connect to another service.  Every time this occurs I have to `ssh-add -D`.  This works fine for a couple of hours but will then crop up again, seemingly for no reason.

Each host is set up in `.ssh/config` with its own identity file listed and I don't have a wildcard statement at the top of the file.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you are looking for but I've switched to termius (https://termius.com) for my ssh needs on both Mac and iOS

Comment: This sounds like a huge security bug (IMO).  It’s best to post feedback to Apple:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/